# Using FileOpenPicker in Windows 8 Store Apps to browse your own resource directory on page startup

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8 Store App page(say PhotoPage.xaml).
In my app I have an embedded Image resource folder in "Assets\Images" in which I have many images present.

[image: Image Folder in App]

Is there a way to populate all the images inside this Images folder on page load of the "PhotoPage.xaml" page.

I tried `FileOpenPicker` but I guess I cant browse a custom folder on `SuggestedStartLocation`.

Here is what I tried :

```
Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
```

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid.aspx)  PickerLocationId can have only few locations..

So is there any way to browse my Images folder on startup(page load) of my PhotoPage.xaml page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `FileOpenPicker`. If you want to populate all the images just get the the Images folder and iterate over its content.

```cs
var installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var images = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets\\Images");
var items = await images.GetItemsAsync();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    // TODO: add image to the Page
}
```